# PHP Laravel "Undefined variable: titles_array". But I have already defined it?

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ReadOnlyBase
{
    protected $titles_array =[];

    public function all(){
        return $this->$titles_array;
    }
    public function get( $id ){
        return $this->$titles_array[$id];
    }


 }
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Title extends ReadOnlyBase
{
    protected $titles_array =['Mr','Ms','Mrs', 'Dr', 'Mx'];
}
```

So on line 12 of the first code block I get the error that the variable titles_array is not defined, however I already have defined it on line 9? How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to do `$this->titles_array`.

Comment: return `$this->titles_array;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->$titles_array` is treating it like a dynamic variable. Remove the `$` off `$titles_array` like so: `$this->titles_array`

Comment: Thank you that worked.  

Could you tell me why do we don't use $ for $this->titles_array but we use it for $this->$titles_array[$id]  ?

Comment: `$this->$titles_array[$id];` should not have the $ on `titles_array`, either. When you prepend a class member with the $ immediately after `$ this->` you are denoting it as a variable variable. This doc page has many good examples: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php